# ideals of quotient ring

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory

Let $A$ denote the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3 \rangle$. Then

1. There are exactly three distinct proper ideals in $A$
2. There is only one prime ideal in $A$
3. $A$ is an integral domain
4. Let $f,g$ be in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $(f+A) (g+A)=0$ in $A$. Then $f(0) g(0)=0$

1...ideals of $R$ containing $M$ corresponds bijectively with ideals of $R/M$

here we have two proper ideals $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle x^2 \rangle$ containing  $\langle x^3 \rangle$ hence first option wrong

2...its true and that is $\langle x \rangle$

3...$(x+I)(x^2+I)=0+I$ hence not ID

4...true using third option. here $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials with constant term $0$

please tell me if any mistake?

Comment: I don't know which notion your book uses.  A "proper ideal" is a bit ambiguous.  Some people use it to mean an ideal which is not the whole ring (therefore, the zero ideal of a nonzero ring is a proper ideal).  Some use it to mean a nonzero ideal which is not the whole ring.  I usually avoid the ambiguity by using the term "proper nonzero ideal."

Comment: Further comment, there seems to be a typo in 4.  Additionally, what is $I$?

Comment: I = $<x^3>$ is ideal generated by  $x^3$

Comment: I think you could say more for the last part. If $fg=0$ in $A$ then $fg=hx^3$. Hence $x$ divides $fg$, and $x$ being prime implies it divides at least one of $f$ or $g$. But this means $f(0)g(0)=0$

Comment: For 1, as Batominovski points out, there are three proper ideals if $(0)$ counts as a proper ideal, which it usually does (except in the zero ring). You should clarify how you get the ideals $(x)$ and $(x^2)$. (The only non-unit divisors of $x^3$, up to constant factors, are $x$, $x^2$ and $x^3$.) For 2, maybe you should prove your statements about which ideals are or aren't prime. For 3, yes. For 4, no. $f$ or $g$ could have a constant term if the other is divisible by $x^3$. The point is that $x^3$ divides $fg$ so $fg$ has no constant term.